# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together (not being able to print the line charts)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have tried the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4msQ.png)

```
(mydata/mydata.iloc[0]*100).plot(figsize = (50,5)); 
plt.show()
```

But got the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1riI.png)

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together (1004, ) (4,)

Comment: Could you please post your code as text? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both code and all relevant data must be posted as text and properly formatted. This is not an option but a requirement.

Comment: (mydata/mydata.iloc[0]*100).plot(figsize = (50,5));
plt.show()

Comment: @Jono2906 I have added the code as text

Comment: Can you post what `mydata` and `mydata.iloc[0]` are?

Comment: @HasanJamil are you trying to normalize `mydata` by the first element of first column?

Comment: @Peyman yes I am trying to normalize the data

Comment: @RafaelC   
tickers = ['PG','MSFT','GE','F']
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t,data_source = 'robinhood',start = '2006-01-04', end = '2010-01-01')['close_price'].values
print mydata

Comment: @HasanJamil so what are you trying to normalize the data wrt? `mydata.iloc[0]` is the first row of your `mydata`. Are you trying to normalize all rows wrt the first row of `mydata`? or you're trying to normalize all columns wrt the first column of `mydata`?

Comment: @Peyman I am trying to normalize the columns with the first row

Comment: @Peyman thank you soo much!!!!! I guess the compiler was not being able to detect it as float.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to recreate your dataset and it looks like your columns are all of type object

```
mydata.dtypes

PG      object
MSFT    object
GE      object
F       object
dtype: object
```

so you'll need to convert it to float before performing the division:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

tickers = ['PG','MSFT','GE','F'] 
mydata = pd.DataFrame() 
for t in tickers: 
    mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t,data_source = 'robinhood',start = '2006-01-04', end = '2010-01-01')['close_price'].values 

((mydata.astype(float)/mydata.astype(float).iloc[0])*100).plot(figsize = (50,5)); 
plt.show()
```

[image]